# how to check polygon contain Point Sequelize and postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

I am working with nodejs, orm is sequelize, database is postgresql. I want to Get
Polygon from another table and where to Vehicles table
here is the code:

```
const geoRegion = await models.GeoRegion.find({
      where: {
        id: id,
      },
    });

    const scooters = await models.Vehicle.findAll({
      where: {
        $and: models.sequelize.where(models.sequelize.fn('ST_Intersects', geoRegion.polygon, models.sequelize.fn('ST_SetSRID', models.sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', models.sequelize.col('lastReportedLocation')), '4326')), true),
      },
      plain: true,
    });
```

the geoRegion has field polygon, I want to check Vehicles inside the polygon
here is the error:

```
SELECT * FROM \"Vehicles\" AS \"Vehicle\" WHERE ST_Intersects(\"lastReportedLocation\", \"type\" = 'Polygon' AND \"coordinates\" IN (ARRAY[ARRAY[105.293,21.145],...)
 "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
"error": "column \"type\" does not exist"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ST_Intersects](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) expects two geometries/geographies as arguments. So, I may guess, your query should look like:

```
select v.* 
from Vehicles v
join geoRegion r
on st_intersects(v.lastReportedLocation, r.polygon)
```

assuming both fields 'lastReportedLocation' from Vehicles table and 'polygon' of geoRegion table contain valid geometries, that's supposed to give you vehicles within area of interest.